# Django formset errors show up in print but not in templates

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates

When I print out the errors in the `form_valid` method the errors are shown, but in the template, the errors are not shown. What am I missing here?

**views.py**

```py
class ParentManage(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    login_url = reverse_lazy('login')
    model = Parent
    form_class = ParentManageForm
    slug_url_kwarg = 'parent_slug'
    template_name_suffix = '-manage'

    def get_object(self):
        return Parent.objects.get(slug=self.kwargs['parent_slug'])

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        data = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.POST:
            data["children"] = ChildFormset(self.request.POST, instance=self.object)
        else:
            data["children"] = ChildFormset(instance=self.object)
        return data

    def form_valid(self, form):
        context = self.get_context_data()
        children = context["children"]
        self.object = form.save()
        if children.is_valid():
            children.instance = self.object
            children.save()
        print(children.errors)
        print(children.non_form_errors)
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        parent = self.get_object()
        return reverse("parent-detail", kwargs={'parent_slug': parent.slug})
```

For the print statement when the POST request process, this is what I see in the shell:

```sh
[{'__all__': ['Child with this Parent and Order already exists.']}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}]
<bound method BaseFormSet.non_form_errors of <django.forms.formsets.ChildFormFormSet object at 0x04F24040>>
```

But it won't show up in the template.

**parent-manage.html:**

```py
<div>
    <form method="post" action="{% url 'parent-manage' parent_slug=parent.slug %}">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form }}
        {{ children.management_form }}
        {% for dict in children.errors %}
            {% for error in dict.values %}
                {{ error }}
            {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
        {% for form in children %}
            <div class="form">
                {{form}}
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    <button type="submit" class="button is-primary">Update</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Note that `UpdateView` isn't designed to handle formsets, it might be better to use a function-based-view, or look at [django-extra-views](https://django-extra-views.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) that provides some views for formsets.

Comment: @Alasdair, I did try `{{ children.non_form_errors }}`. I'll try a function based view.